# in postgres, which has only md5 encryption, what is best way to save password?

Tags: security, postgresql, encryption, passwords

PostgreSQL only has MD5 for encryption for storing passwords.

From reading hack logs, it seems that MD5 alone is not a very secure way to store the password.

I have been using MD5 of MD5 — MD5 once at the client and then MD5 again at the database — but I don't know that this is much stronger.

First, is it necessary to beef-up storing the passwords? And second, what would be a simple, effective, cross-language approach?

Comment: Voter to close: would you mind explaining your reasoning?

Comment: extensive use of stored procedures, so have traditionally tested everything at the db level before porting to the app level.  perhaps you're right - perhaps my approach has blinded me to the obvious.

Comment: Of course, you could also use `pgcrypto`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html … But if it were me, I would just do it at the application level :)

Comment: pgcrypto - also linked to by @plundra - looks great.  personally I feel better knowing the db will always encrypt sensitive info regardless of app bugs, but having all the app code in one place makes perfect sense as well.

Comment: md5 hashing an md5 hash is weaker than a single hash.  Google it.

Comment: MD5 is NOT a method of encryption; be careful with your use of terminology here, it may lead to misunderstandings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing the `pgcrypto` extension gives you a suite of functions and tools to use.
Among those are the ability to use `bcrypt`, which is a good way of storing passwords.

If not using it in postgres, you might consider it outside in the language you use.

Relevant links: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html for the postgres-parts and http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ for motivation/explanation as to why you'd want to use it.

Comment: Ah, yes — clearly the early hour hasn't helped my memory. bcrypt is definitely preferable to sha256 when being used for password hasing (and scrypt would be even better…)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do the hashing in the database. Provided you base your salt on something like the user name which can be determined without access to the hashed password, it's just as secure to has at the application level:

```
password_hash = sha256(user_name + password)
user_id = query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE name=? and password_hash=?",
                user_name, password_hash).first()
```

Or you could check the username and password in two separate steps and use the user ID as the salt:

```
user_id, password_hash = query("SELECT id, password_hash FROM user WHERE name=?",
                               user_name).first()
if password_hash != sha256(user_id + password):
    raise Exception("authentication failed")
```

Comment: the user_name is volatile - would salting on the usr_id work as well?

Comment: Sure, that would work too: `user_id, password_hash = query("SELECT id, password_hash FROM user WHERE name=?", user_name); if password_hash != sha256(user_id + password): raise Exception("authentication failed")`